# Compute distance between multiple sets of coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, distance, pairwise

I have a dataset of coordinates that are merged by time into one dataframe, with the individual IDs in the header. For example:

```
> Date_time<-c("2015/03/04 01:00:00","2015/03/04 02:00:00","2015/03/04 03:00:00","2015/03/04 04:00:00")
> lat.1<-c(63.81310,63.83336,63.83250,63.82237)
> long.1<-c(-149.1176,-149.0193,-149.0249,-149.0408)
> lat.2<-c(63.85893 ,63.85885,63.86108,63.86357)
> long.2<-c(-151.1336,-151.1336,-151.1236,-151.1238)
> lat.3<-c(63.87627,63.87670, 63.85044,63.85052)
> long.3<-c(-149.5029,-149.5021,-149.5199,-149.5199)
> 
> data<-data.frame(Date_time,lat.1,long.1,lat.2,long.2,lat.3,long.3)
> data
          Date_time lat.1  long.1  lat.2  long.2  lat.3  long.3
1 2015/03/04 01:00:00 63.8131 -149.1176 63.85893 -151.1336 63.87627 -149.5029
2 2015/03/04 02:00:00 63.8131 -149.1176 63.85893 -151.1336 63.87627 -149.5029
3 2015/03/04 03:00:00 63.8131 -149.1176 63.85893 -151.1336 63.87627 -149.5029
4 2015/03/04 04:00:00 63.8131 -149.1176 63.85893 -151.1336 63.87627 -149.5029
```

I want to calculate the distance between each of the individuals, so between 1 and 2, 1 and 3, and 2 and 3. My dataframe has many more individuals than this so I am hoping to apply a loop function.

I can do them individually using

```
> data$distbetween12<-distHaversine(cbind(data$long.1,data$lat.1), cbind(data$long.2,data$lat.2))
> data$distbetween12
[1] 99083.48 99083.48 99083.48 99083.48
```

But can I calculate all the pairwise distances without typing out every pair combination?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that relies on the `combn` function to generate the necessary combinations. If you have more than 3 pairs of `lat`, `long` columns, just change the first number in the `combn` function to the correct number of pairs.

Note this solution also requires that your columns strictly adhere to the naming `lat.1` `long.1`, `lat.2`, `long.2` etc.

```r
 combos <- combn(3, 2)
 
 cbind(data, as.data.frame(`colnames<-`(apply(combos, 2, function(x) { 
   lats <- paste0("lat.", x)
   lons <- paste0("long.", x)
   geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(data[[lons[1]]], data[[lats[1]]]), 
                            cbind(data[[lons[2]]], data[[lats[2]]]))
   }), apply(combos, 2, paste, collapse = " v "))))
 
#>             Date_time    lat.1    long.1    lat.2    long.2    lat.3    long.3
#> 1 2015/03/04 01:00:00 63.81310 -149.1176 63.85893 -151.1336 63.87627 -149.5029
#> 2 2015/03/04 02:00:00 63.83336 -149.0193 63.85885 -151.1336 63.87670 -149.5021
#> 3 2015/03/04 03:00:00 63.83250 -149.0249 63.86108 -151.1236 63.85044 -149.5199
#> 4 2015/03/04 04:00:00 63.82237 -149.0408 63.86357 -151.1238 63.85052 -149.5199
#>       1 v 2    1 v 3    2 v 3
#> 1  99083.48 20172.13 79974.87
#> 2 103778.13 24168.80 80014.97
#> 3 103020.61 24374.46 78669.90
#> 4 102317.93 23724.27 78680.61
```